# Надо создать не полный круг в котором будет текст

Tags: css

Вот картинка как должен выйти круг и внутри проценты. Буду благодарен каждому кто поможет мне.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот тут есть примеры на любой вкус: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350504/circular-percent-progress-bar

Comment: Разобрались? Или ещё нужно?